# angular material - Select header Error

Tags: angularjs, select, angular-material

> I get this error "Error: md-input-container can only have *one*
>   child input, textarea or select element!" when trying to
>   implement a Select Header.

This is my code

```
  <md-input-container>
    <label>Vegetables</label>
    <md-select ng-model="selectedVegetables" md-on-close="clearSearchTerm()" data-md-container-class="selectdemoSelectHeader" multiple="">
      <md-select-header class="demo-select-header">
        <input ng-model="searchTerm" type="search" placeholder="Search for a vegetable.." class="demo-header-searchbox _md-text">
      </md-select-header>
      <md-optgroup label="vegetables">
        <md-option ng-value="vegetable" ng-repeat="vegetable in vegetables |
          filter:searchTerm">{{vegetable}}</md-option>
      </md-optgroup>
    </md-select>
  </md-input-container>
```

When i remove the following then i dont get any errors.

```
  <md-select-header class="demo-select-header">
    <input ng-model="searchTerm" type="search" placeholder="Search for a vegetable.." class="demo-header-searchbox _md-text">
  </md-select-header>
```

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong or have experienced the same thing?

Comment: what is the version you are using? i don't get any error here https://plnkr.co/edit/s33RpP?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for your answer. 

I was using 1.1.0-rc3, but updated the angular material version to 1.1.0-rc5 after reading this https://github.com/angular/material/issues/9091. 

And now its working. Apparently i was not the only one who encountered this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update the material verison from `1.1.0-rc3`  to the latest version  `1.1.0-rc.5`, it should work,

Here is the working [`Plunker`](https://plnkr.co/edit/s33RpP?p=preview).,

Comment: Actualy the latest version is 1.1.0-rc.5.